# Why is @UIViewController referenced in UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I was looking through `UIView.h` and I noticed on line 123 a `@class UIViewController;`

I see there is a `UIViewController *_viewDelegate;` on line 133 but I don't understand why it would have a delegate?

Comment: You don't have to understand, because it's private to Apple and not anything you should worry about

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not practical.  According to our FAQ, your question should be "
    a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

Comment: `_viewDelegate` is currently (iOS 8) used to handle some of the responder chain logic in UIView.  But as the others have said, you needn't concern yourself with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, that'll be so that the controller can deliver `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and the similar messages.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate used when the view controller adds a subview to its own view or add a view to a window.  Also used so that a `UIView` can call `nextResponder`.